# Is it ok to use User.find in a view partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models

1. User
2. Business (acts_as_commentable using acts_as_commentable gem)
3. Comment (belongs to user)

On the Business show page I display all the comments associated with that business:

```
Name:<%= @business.name %>
<%= render @business.comments %>
```

comments partial

```
Comment: <%= comment.comment %><br >
By: <%= User.find(comment.user_id).name %>
```

Is there a better way to display the name of the user instead of using User.find?

Here are my models
User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
end
```

Business

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :category

  has_reputation :votes, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum

  acts_as_commentable
end
```

Comment

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  include ActsAsCommentable::Comment

  attr_accessible :comment, :user_id

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  default_scope :order => 'created_at ASC'

  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can just use this:

```
<%= comment.user.name %>
```

Rails will handle loading for you.

Comment: And do not forget add `.includes(:user)` (I think in this way: `<%= render @business.comments.includes(:user) %>` to avoid N+1 query problem

Answer (score 1):

Each comment belongs to a user. So, you just have to get the user this way

```
comment.user.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is:

```
<%= comment.user.try(:name) %>
```

I see you have `validates :user_id, presence: true` to have `user`. But if the use has deleted, `comment.user.name` will put the error.

Or you can use:

```
<%= comment.user.blank? ? "Visitor" : comment.user.name %>
```